# equivalent functionality to multiprocessing.Pool's join in pathos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I'm using `multiprocessing.Process` to prevent some function from running for too long.

I'd like to use `pathos` instead of python's `multiprocessing` (due to it's ability to handle things that the standard multiprocessing package can't), but it seems like some functionality is lacking: I can't find anything in pathos which allows for `join` with a timeout argument.

I'm hoping there is something of the sort which will allow me to terminate a process once some time has passed.

(I'm using windows, so the simplest alternative - using `signal` - is not possible, and the alternatives seem extremely complicated)

Comment: Have you looked at `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: @RolandSmith I wasn't even aware this existed. However, it still won't work in the interactive interpreter according to the documentation, which is a feature I am hoping to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  You might want to try `multiprocess`, which is a fork of `multiprocessing` (and is what is underneath `pathos`).  You should already have it installed if you have `pathos` installed.

You can get to `Process` either of these two ways, where it has all of the same functionality as in `multiprocessing` (plus the additional serialization capabilities from `dill`):

```
>>> import pathos
>>> pathos.helpers.mp.Process
<class 'multiprocess.process.Process'>
>>> import multiprocess
>>> multiprocess.Process
<class 'multiprocess.process.Process'>
```

So, any object found in `multiprocessing` with a `timeout` argument can also be found as above.

Comment: Thank you. if I recall correctly, I tried accessing `pathos.helpers.mp`, but it's `__file__` attribute seemed to lead me back to the original `multiprocessing`, so I assumed it was just a reference to the standard python multiprocessing package.